# Dynamics CRM least restrictive OOTB read only role

Tags: security, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Wanted to know, what is the best OOTB security role to copy in order to create a new security role that enables read only access to CRM records.

As I’m looking to give this as a base role to all users then look to extend by creating other roles which have more permissions such as a create and update role.

Comment: Just my personal opinion but I think you'll be better off starting with a blank custom security role and tick all "Read" privilege columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take **Scheduler** or **Sales Person** OOTB security role & clone, so that the hidden privileges may come part of it. Also it has least work to do, meaning removing unnecessary privileges and adding any custom entity privileges.

Open the newly cloned role, you can click on left entity name headers,  for ex. **Attribute map**. This will wipe out to grant full the existing rights on rotation.

Then grant/revoke the minimum privileges by clicking top headers, for ex. **Create**. or **Read** in your case.

This is the cleanest & quickest way to make sure of giving minimal access rights.

Verify all the [minimum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2016/11/24/minimum-privileges-required-to-login-microsoft-dynamics-365) is present to avoid headache.

[image]

Update:

Able to find this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2009/08/04/viewing-all-crm-privileges-including-hidden-privileges/) though old but good reference.

Comment: Could you explain what *hidden privileges* you expect to (maybe) come with cloning an existing role?

Comment: @Filburt In my experience I always faced issues when I start from scratch and [am not alone](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/211958).. thats why we say hidden

Comment: That seems rather a shortcoming of the quoted blog post listing the minimum privileges than a *hidden privilege*. Don't get me wrong but when it comes to security issues, I'd rather not see cargo cult-ish recipes relying on magic happening. If the intention is to reliably create a least-privilege security role imho starting with a blank one would be the true way; copying an OOTB role only a somewhat-lesser-privileges role. It will make a difference if you will be held responsible for every single privilege ticked on or off.

Comment: @Filburt sorry for not being clear earlier. Did you get a chance to see Mark & Nick responses from the linked community post..?

Comment: Yes, I did see those but Nick just claims as well there being hidden privileges without giving any evidence what they are. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/security-dev/how-role-based-security-control-access-entities) clearly state *"... you can create custom roles using the predefined roles as a template, or you can define a new set of roles."* without any indication that creating a blank role will lack any privilege.

Comment: @Filburt that comes with experience.. MS assuming we will use a minimum one of OOB role then will go with custom role in addition. If you give only one custom role created from scratch user will face issues.. sometimes we have to give addon OOB role & revoke it once user logged in for the first time.. can try your luck.. today also we are getting some weird privilege error for some activity card blah blah error..

Comment: @Filburt FYR: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2009/08/04/viewing-all-crm-privileges-including-hidden-privileges/

Comment: Thanks, this answers my initial comment. Plain hard facts from the database.